# How to change database

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am currently on a vps from ovh with prestashop 1.7.5. I ordered a CloudDB database. 
I would like to know the handling to follow to be able to change the database because I do not find a solution to my problem.

thank you so much

PS: I'm a beginner with PrestaShop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using your FTP client or file manager open this file:
   `/app/config/parameters.php`
2. Find the lines with `database_host`, `database_name`, `database_user` and
   `database_password` parameters.
3. Replace existing values of that params with the new ones.
4. Save the file and upload it back to the server.

All done! Open your site in the browser and check whether it works.

```
<?php return array (
  'parameters' =>
  array (
    'database_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'database_port' => '',
    'database_name' => 'your_database_name',
    'database_user' => 'your_database_user',
    'database_password' => 'your_database_password',
    'database_prefix' => 'ps_',
    'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',
    'mailer_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'mailer_user' => NULL,
    'mailer_password' => NULL,
    'secret' => 'Vz6rVXVYNWYt7E6Fvfvdfvg34MCdc97h3IttReewVIxNOu7wHAoS',
    'ps_caching' => 'CacheMemcache',
    'ps_cache_enable' => false,
    'ps_creation_date' => '2017-05-22',
    'locale' => 'en-US',
    'cookie_key' => 'xduROM3yvjDSym43CvfdvFDVD47YG8zCrVruNFjjZ3NUb7Ut9',
    'cookie_iv' => '7kBvdfvgh',
    'new_cookie_key' => 'def00000766ffa61aae49b279evfsdvsdfvsfdvfdvwerr324r3frdfveb1afedc8702a964f0a1f6828bf1623ca54efad10ed4bbfb289beec62b01a3062d4c3ce78254157',
  ),
);
```

Comment: i have that "500 Server Error"

Comment: You only need to change `database_host`, `database_name`, `database_user` and `database_password`

Comment: `database_host`, `database_name`, `database_user `and `database_password `are changed.

Comment: i've transfert all db. Del cache ("prod" file), but, error 500...

Comment: I resolve my problem, i forget to put the `database_port`. Thanks for helping